# Devextreme-Vue template How can i find input for v-model?

Tags: vue.js, devextreme

i wanna add user and i think i use v-model but can't find it anyone how can i use v-model for devextreme template?

```html
      <DxPaging :enabled="false"/>
      <DxEditing
        :allow-updating="true"
        :allow-deleting="false"
        :confirm-delete="false"
        :allow-adding="true"
        mode="popup"
      >
        <DxPopup
          :show-title="true"
          :width="700"
          :height="525"
          title="Kullanıcı Ekle"
        />
          <DxItem
            :col-count="2"
            :col-span="2"
            item-type="group"
          >
            <DxItem data-field="name" caption="Adı"/>
            <DxItem data-field="surname"/>
            <DxItem data-field="userName"/>
            <DxItem data-field="password"/>
            <DxItem data-field="role"/>
          </DxItem>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.